# Dockerfile of console application that accept arguments in Commons CLI style

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, apache-commons-cli

I have a java console application that I package as jar and run it as

```
java -jar target/myProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -arg1 145 -arg2 345 -arg3 99
```

I want to run the same command inside a container and pass these arguments (arg1, arg2, arg3) to docker run command. My docker file look like:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/myProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar myProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /myProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" ]
```

then I try to run the image as follows:

```
docker run myProject:0.3 -e  -arg1 145 -arg2 345 -arg3 99
```

but my program don't get the arguments. what I'm missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the ENV command in the `DOCKERFILE` so that you can receive the arguments that you are passing in and then pass that onto the `ENTRYPOINT` script

Dockerfile will look something like this

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ENV arg1
ENV arg2
ENV arg3
ADD target/myProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar myProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /myProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ${arg1} ${arg2} ${arg3}" ]
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 1):

The arguments you pass to `docker run` are the command it's running, which it appends to the end of the entry point. So what you're doing is equivalent to running:

```
sh -c "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /myProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" -arg1 145 -arg2 345 -arg3 99
```

Presented like this, you can see that the arguments are going to `sh` and not to `java`. If you want to combine a set of options that you define when you build the image with a set of options that you can append at runtime, you'll need to use a wrapper script or something similar.

1. Create file wrapper.sh and make it executable:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /myProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar "$@"
   ```
2. Add it to your container with `ADD wrapper.sh /bin` in the Dockerfile
3. Change your entrypoint to `["/bin/wrapper.sh"]`
4. Now, when you run the image, it will append the arguments to the `java` command line

Comment: Something I learned while crafting this answer: `ENTRYPOINT /bin/wrapper.sh` won't get the arguments but `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/wrapper.sh"]` will

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I decided to create only one ENV argument that I used to pass all my arguments in one string like this docker run -e args="-arg1=145 -arg2=345 -arg3=99" myProject:0.3

Comment: That'll work for most cases, but beware spaces in your arguments.